# I can't seem to figure out how to print the values I've assigned to my objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist, methods, constructor

This might be an easy answer but I'm new and my professor hasn't been much help, also feel free to correct my terminology. Essentially I have a class "Employee" and I'm trying to add several instances of it to an ArrayList to be printed later in Main. It looks kind of like this:

```
    public Employee(int id, String name, String bday, String gender, String job, int org)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.bday = bday;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.job = job;
    this.org = org;
}
```

All I really need to know how to do is print the values I've managed to assign to the constructor i.e. when I call a specific object from the ArrayList I'll be able to print the object's specific id, name, etc. I figured out that I can do it by creating a method for each individual variable but that would be really messy and inefficient, I'm looking for one method to call that would be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Override [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) in `Employee`. Something like,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Employee id=%d, name=%s, bday=%s, gender=%s, job=%s, org=%s",
            id, name, bday, gender, job, org);
}
```

Then whenever you try and `print` it, the `toString` of `Employee` will be invoked.

```
System.out.println(new Employee(1, "Test", "A Birthday",
        "Yes", "Something", "Somewhere"));
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for, although I guess I forgot to mention I'm trying to fill in the information via Scanner inputs. How does that change things?

Comment: @2004DodgeNeon It does not. You print `Employee` instances.